# Deploy Spring Boot and MySQL using Docker compose

Tags: mysql, spring, docker

I used `mvn clean package` to get my target directory and .jar file. Then, I try to put it and mysql database into docker containers but keep failing. It can be executed perfectly outside the containers.

I try to set up the environments through docker compose file, so I guess the application.properties does not matter here. Correct me if I am wrong.

Current structure of my dir:

[image]

The error I got:

> java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql-container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: inventory
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  spring-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: spring-container
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-db:3306/inventory?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: root
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Use a base image with OpenJDK Java 17 installed
FROM openjdk:17

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the packaged Spring Boot application JAR file into the container
COPY target/smartstock-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app

# Specify the command to run the Spring Boot application when the container starts
CMD ["java", "-jar", "smartstock-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

application.properties:

```
#information for connect to MySQL database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql-db:3306/inventory?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#auto building table in database according to entity class we have
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#show what sql is jpa using
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#reduce logging information. only shows warm
logging.level.root=warn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following settings. This setting is originally from [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ekBqIvAGY4&t=4s).

application.properties:

```
   #information for connect to MySQL database
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:${MYSQL_PORT:3306}/test
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=root
    spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    #auto building table in database according to entity class we have
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    #show what sql is jpa using
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    #reduce logging information. only shows warm
    logging.level.root=warn
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services: 
  springboot-app:
   # container_name: spring-app
    image: springbooot-app
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8082:8080 
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysqldb
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
  mysqldb: 
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports: 
     - 3307:3306   
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: test
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Use a base image with OpenJDK Java 17 installed
FROM openjdk:17

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the packaged Spring Boot application JAR file into the container
COPY target/smartstock-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app

# Specify the command to run the Spring Boot application when the container starts
CMD ["java", "-jar", "smartstock-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Answer (score 2):

When working with Dockerized databases, it's crucial to use the container name for the host instead of the service name in your code.

Therefore, your connection string should be:

```
jdbc:mysql://mysql-container:3306/inventory?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

as you specified your MySQL container name on your `docker-compose.yaml`.

To ensure compatibility both locally and in Docker, adjust your application.properties file as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=${MYSQL_URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false}
```

and set on your `docker-compose.yaml` on the spring-app service the environment variable:

```
environment:
    MYSQL_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-container:3306/inventory?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

or

you can specify just the host part, like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/inventory?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
```

and set on your `docker-compose.yaml` on the spring-app service the env:

```
environment:
    MYSQL_HOST: mysql-container
```

This way when you run locally without the env it will use your localhost database and when you Dockerize your application you will pass an env with the correct host for your connection string.

You can see an example on running an application with Dockerized PostgreSQL on this Baeldung article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-postgresql-docker

#### UPDATE:

Another thing that you should do to work is add an restart-policy to your spring-app. The depends_on keyword on his own is not enough.

This is what happens when you execute the `docker compose up`. The docker will initialize your mysql-db, and after it initializes the depends_on policy will make your spring-app initializes in sequence, but there is the problem, your database is initialized, but not fully loaded and working. So when you load your spring-app it will not find a database and will fail.

To prevent this, you should add an restart policy to your spring-app, so when it loads and not found a database it will fail but will start another on sequence. Add it like this:

```yaml
      spring-app:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: spring-container
        ports:
          - "8082:8080"
        depends_on:
          - mysql-db
        environment:
          MYSQL_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-container:3306/inventory?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
          MYSQL_USERNAME: root
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
        deploy:
          restart_policy:
            condition: on-failure
            max_attempts: 10
```

with this it will try to restart your application until it runs properly, at max 10 times.

The name of the environment variable doesn't matter, as long as is the same as you specify on your `application.properties`. As a convention I recommend you to use the MYSQL_URL name for the env, because SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL gives an impression that is an Spring provided property. You should end with something like this:

```
    spring.datasource.url=${MYSQL_URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventory?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false}
    spring.datasource.username=${MYSQL_USERNAME:root}
    spring.datasource.password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD:root}
```

**Attention:** The spring.datasource.url is not an environment variable, just what is inside the ${  } is one.

I would also recommend you to connect your app and database to the same docker network. Providing better isolation, security and communication, preventing from eventual communication issues.

Following everything you should end with an docker-compose like this:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql-container
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: inventory
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - springmysql

  spring-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: spring-container
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
    environment:
      MYSQL_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-container:3306/inventory?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        max_attempts: 10
    networks:
      - springmysql

networks:
  springmysql:
    name: springmysql
```

Comment: I have changed it to the name of the container but it still does work. Also, should I be using MYSQL_URL or SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL? I tried with both. Either of them led to the same error. It seems that the spring just can not connect to mysql in my docker container and I really do not know why.

Comment: Edited the answer, hope it solves your problems now!